# How can I send E-Mails through python django frequently with a cronjob?

Tags: django, cron, smtp

I try to run a function in django every 5 minutes. For this I user the django-crontab package. The function which should run, checks for some conditions in the database and if they are met, sends an e-mail to the user of the app.

I have django 4 running on my linux ubuntu 20.04 server. I added the cronjob via `python3 manage.py crontab add` (in activated virtual environment). But then I wondered why the cronjob is not running. I tried to execute the job by hand and it worked.

I think the problem boils down to this: When I'm in the activated virtual environment and run the crontab with "python3 manage.py crontab run " it works. But when I run it outside of the virtual environment I get the following error:

```
Failed to complete cronjob at ('*/5 * * * *', 'evaluation_tool.scripts.cron.send_mail_if_classeval_ended')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/amadeus/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_crontab/crontab.py", line 145, in run_job
    func(*job_args, **job_kwargs)
  File "/var/www/amadeus/evaluation_tool/scripts/cron.py", line 12, in send_mail_if_classeval_ended
    send_mail_time_over_class_evaluation(class_evaluation=class_evaluation.pk,
  File "/var/www/amadeus/evaluation_tool/scripts/email_handler.py", line 122, in send_mail_time_over_class_evaluation
    send_falko_mail("AMADEUS Evaluation abgeschlossen", message, to_email_address)
  File "/var/www/amadeus/evaluation_tool/scripts/email_handler.py", line 34, in send_falko_mail
    msg.send(fail_silently=False)
  File "/var/www/amadeus/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 298, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/var/www/amadeus/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 124, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/var/www/amadeus/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 87, in open
    self.connection.starttls(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 769, in starttls
    self.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 611, in ehlo_or_helo_if_needed
    if not (200 <= self.ehlo()[0] <= 299):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 451, in ehlo
    self.putcmd(self.ehlo_msg, name or self.local_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 378, in putcmd
    self.send(f'{s}{CRLF}')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 365, in send
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected('please run connect() first')
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first
```

Why is the connection to the SMTP Server working in the activated virtual environment but not outside, which is the desired way using a cronjob?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I set certain environment variables for SMTP Host, User and Password. But crontab cannot access them. So there are two possibilities:

1. Add them directly to the head of cron file via crontab -e

```
EMAIL_HOST=XXX
EMAIL_HOST_USER=XXX
EMAIL_PASS=XXX
```

2. Add them via a django-crontab argument in settings.py:

```
CRONTAB_COMMAND_PREFIX = 'EMAIL_HOST=XXX\nEMAIL_HOST_USER=XXX\nEMAIL_PASS=XXX'
```